# JS syntax breaks the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code in my external JS file:

```
var myDiv = $(".myDiv");

if (myDiv.css('left') == 'auto') { 
    var pos = myDiv.position(); 
    myDiv.css({ "left:" + pos.left + "px", "top:" + pos.top + "px" }); 
}
```

It appears that the following line breaks my page:

```
myDiv.css({ "left:" + pos.left + "px", "top:" + pos.top + "px" });
```

If I comment it out everything works fine, except this functionality, obviously.

And if I put the values in alert I get them correctly as well.

```
alert(pos.left + ' ' + pos.top)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to create an `object` by passing in 2 `strings`.

Should probably look like this:

```
myDiv.css({
  "left": pos.left + "px",
  "top": pos.top + "px"
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple fix, use javascript object notation for the css properties. Move the colon outside the quotes:

`myDiv.css({ "left": pos.left + "px", "top": pos.top + "px" });`

Answer (score -1):

You need quotation marks around the values in the object you pass to the .css() function:

```
myDiv.css({ "left: '" + pos.left + "px'", "top: '" + pos.top + "px'" });
```

Comment: This still isn't valid JS object syntax.  It should be: `{key: val, key: val}`